# Migrating from Babel 6 to 7 export defaults are undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, babeljs

I've been tasked with migrating a repo from babel 6 to 7.

Babel 6 `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-3" ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
    }]
  ] 
}
```

Babel 7 `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", {
    "targets": {
      "node": "current"
    }
  }]],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

with:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
```

The interesting thing is when I `nodemon --exec babel-node .` it seems most of my default exports are `undefined`.

The project structure is as follows:

```
- src
   - models
   - controllers
   - ...etc
```

`./src/models/index.js` imports a bunch of the models, adds `Sequelize` relations, etc. and then exports, eg:

```
// models/index.js
import ExampleModel from 'models/ExampleModel';
import OtherModel from 'models/OtherModel';

//...

ExampleModel.belongsTo(OtherModel, { as: 'other_model' });

// ...

export {
  ExampleModel,
  OtherModel
}
```

Then individual models import others from `models/index.js` to set themselves up:

```
// models/ExampleModel.js
import { OtherModel } from 'models';

const ExampleModel = db.define('ExampleModel', {
   // ...
   otherModelId: {
      type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
      references: { model: OtherModel, key: 'id' },
    },
   // ...
});

export default ExampleModel
```

`OtherModel` set up is very much the same:

```
    const OtherModel = db.define('OtherModel', {
      // ...
    });

    export default OtherModel;
```

`ExampleModel` will throw an error saying:

```
/src/models/index.js:23
    return _OtherModel.default;
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
    at Object.get [as OtherModel] (src/models/index.js:23:24)
    at Object.OtherModel (src/models/ExampleModel.js:82:28)
```

If I instead just do a regular import `import OtherModel from 'models/OtherModel';` everything works perfectly.

Is there some sort of a plugin that I'm missing that will allow me to export imports like this? I've tried a bunch of stuff and Haven't had any success.

---

EDIT:

If I do a `import * as models from 'models'` in `models/ExampleModel`, I get:

```
{
   OtherModel: [Getter],
   AnotherExportedModel: [Getter],
   // ...etc
}
```